# Variable Javascript no reconocida en estadística

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema
Estoy haciendo una estadística donde trago los datos por medio ajax desde un php
Hasta aca todo funciona bien. El problema es cuando quiero colocar los datos guardados en una variable de javascript en el script de la estadistica
Dejo el código para que se entienda mejor

Este el el ajax que trae el resultado

```
  var datos;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "consultas.php",
      success: function (response) {
        datos = response;
        console.log(datos);
      },
    });
  });
```

Y este el es código que genera la estadística

```
var ctx1 = $("#worldwide-sales").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: [datos],  // aca está el problema
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "USA",
          data: [15, 30, 55, 65, 60, 80, 95],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .7)",
        },
        {
          label: "UK",
          data: [8, 35, 40, 60, 70, 55, 75],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .5)",
        },
        {
          label: "UK",
          data: [8, 35, 40, 60, 70, 55, 75],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .5)",
        },
        {
          label: "AU",
          data: [12, 25, 45, 55, 65, 70, 60],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .3)",
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
    },
  });
```

En la linea que marco que está el problema es donde no me esta mostrando el contenido de la variable "datos"

El contenido que tiene datos es esta cadena: "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"

Si yo copio y pedo esa cadena reemplazando la variable, anda perfecto. Es como que no lee el contenido de la variable o definitivamente la estoy llamando mal en ese lugar

Espero puedan ayudarme
Gracias

**Actualziació:**
Agrego el código modificado con error al llamar a la function

```
var datos;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "consultas.php",
          success: function(response) {
              datos = response;
              estadistica(datos);
          },
      });
  });

  function estadistica(datos) {
    var ctx1 = $("#worldwide-sales").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: [datos],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "USA",
            data: [15, 30, 55, 65, 60, 80, 95],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .7)",
          },
          {
            label: "UK",
            data: [8, 35, 40, 60, 70, 55, 75],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .5)",
          },
          {
            label: "UK",
            data: [8, 35, 40, 60, 70, 55, 75],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .5)",
          },
          {
            label: "AU",
            data: [12, 25, 45, 55, 65, 70, 60],
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .3)",
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
      },
    });
  }
```

El problema ahora es como que lo coloca al texto pero como literal al parecer, no es que lo toma como array. Dejo dos imágenes.

[image: Así es si escribo el texto directo en la label labels: ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"],]

[image: Así es si lo traigo por la variable javascript]

**En la primer** imagen es si escribo el texto directo en la label `labels: ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"],`

**En la segunda** imagen es si lo traigo por la variable javascript

No se que puede ser realmente

Comment: Los datos que se traen de la petición no están disponibles hasta que el servidor responda. Pero para cuando el servidor responda, ya el código de la gráfica se habrá ejecutado y habrá explotado porque `datos` es `undefined`. Así funciona la asincronía en javascript. Para solucionarlo, mete el código de la gráfica dentro del callback de  `success`. Alternativamente mete el código de la gráfica en una función que reciba una variable `datos` y llama esa función dentro de success.

Comment: gracias por responder. Hice lo que me has dicho y funciona pero no me muestra bien  el grafico. Tienes idea que es lo que está mal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los datos que se traen de la petición no están disponibles hasta que el servidor responda. Pero para cuando el servidor responda, ya el código de la gráfica se habrá ejecutado y habrá explotado porque `datos` es `undefined`. Así funciona la asincronía en javascript.

Para solucionarlo, mete el código de la gráfica dentro del callback de `success`. Alternativamente mete el código de la gráfica en una función que reciba una variable `datos` y llama esa función dentro de `success`.

---

### Actualización

La variable `datos` ya es un `array`, por tanto, cuando pones `labels: [datos]` estás metiendo un array dentro de un array, por eso no te sale bien la gráfica. Para solucionarlo, usa simplemente `labels: datos`. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
var datos = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"]
estadistica(datos)

function estadistica(datos) {
    var ctx1 = $("#worldwide-sales").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: datos,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "USA",
                    data: [15, 30, 55, 65, 60, 80, 95],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .7)",
                },
                {
                    label: "UK",
                    data: [8, 35, 40, 60, 70, 55, 75],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .5)",
                },
                {
                    label: "UK",
                    data: [8, 35, 40, 60, 70, 55, 75],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .5)",
                },
                {
                    label: "AU",
                    data: [12, 25, 45, 55, 65, 70, 60],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .3)",
                },
            ],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
        },
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>

 <canvas id="worldwide-sales"></canvas>
```